# Jquery if (is visible) / else

Tags: jquery, if-statement, visibility

Here's my situation : First when load the page I Hide menus "menu(2a,3a,4a,5a,6a)" exept "menu1a" that i hide "menu1b". Then I want to click in a button that have that check if "menu1a" is visible or not and run a condition, so when I click in him again the if condition shouldn't happen becouse in the button should hide it.

Here's the Html :

```
        <div class="main">
            <div class="menu" id="menu1a"></div>
            <div class="menu" id="menu1b"></div>
            <div class="menu" id="menu2a"></div>
            <div class="menu" id="menu2b"></div>
            <div class="menu" id="menu3a"></div>
            <div class="menu" id="menu3b"></div>
            <div class="menu" id="menu4a"></div>
            <div class="menu" id="menu4b"></div>
            <div class="menu" id="menu5a"></div>
            <div class="menu" id="menu5b"></div>
            <div class="menu" id="menu6a"></div>
            <div class="menu" id="menu6b"></div>
        </div>
```

And the Script :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
          $('.container2').hide();
          $('.container3').hide();
          $('.container4').hide();
          $('.container5').hide();
          $('.container6').hide();
          $('#menu1b').hide();
          $('#menu2a').hide();
          $('#menu3a').hide();
          $('#menu4a').hide();
          $('#menu5a').hide();
          $('#menu6a').hide();
});
$('#menu2b').click(function(){
if($('#menu1a').is(':visible'))
    {
        $('.main').delay(50).animate({marginTop : "-=160px"},{duration: 1000});
        $('.footer').delay(220).animate({marginTop : "-=150px"},{duration: 1000});
        $('.container2').animate({marginTop : "-=90px"},{duration: 0}).delay(200).show(0).slideUp(0).slideDown(150);
    }
      $('#menu1a').show();$('#menu1b').hide();
      $('#menu2a').hide();$('#menu2b').show();
      $('#menu3a').hide();$('#menu3b').show();
      $('#menu4a').hide();$('#menu4b').show();
      $('#menu5a').hide();$('#menu5b').show();
      $('#menu6a').hide();$('#menu6b').show();
});
```

UPDATE : The if condition is beeing ignored... the menu is "margin top" every time i click on it , seems like #menu1a is visible all the time.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: And whats the problem/question?

Comment: UPDATE : The if condition is beeing ignored... the menu is "margin top" every time i click on it , seems like #menu1a is visible all the time

Comment: your click method is not inside the ready function.

Comment: @user2136984 Of course is it visible all the time or what do you expect from `$('#menu1a').show();` in your click handler?